# Understanding rxjs with angular and HTTP

Tags: http, angular, rxjs

Im tying to work with angular 2 and rxjs and i have encounter a problem.

Im trying to do a basic login: here is the code:

```
class LoginPage{
    ctor(private auth:AuthService) {}

    login(cred) {
        this.auth.login(cred).subscribe( res=> this.navigateToHome()
    }
}

class AuthService {
    ctor(private http:AuthHttp) {}

    login(cred){
        return this.http.post(url, cred).subscribe(res => this.onLoginSuccess())

     }
}

class AuthHttp extends Http {
   ctor (.....)

   post(...) {
     // Add some headers
      return super.post(..)
   }
}
```

Now first of all the wont work since the `login` in `AuthService` is now returning `Subscription` object and not an `Observable`, In addtional  if take the `login` function and refactoring it like that:

```
login(cred) {
   var obs = this.http.post(url, cred)
   obs.subscribe(res=> this.onLoginSuccess())
   retrun obs
 }
```

This Causes the http request to invoke two times..

So my problem is: how can I know im my `loginPage` that the subscriber that invokes the `onLoginSuccess` is done?

How can i avoid the 2 time  request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [`share()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md)?

If you need to subscribe on `AuthService.login()`, then `login()` must return `Observable`. But you need also do something on login inside `AuthService`, isnt it? `share()` let you subscribe on login inside `AuthService` and return `Observable`.

```
class AuthService {
    ctor(private http:AuthHttp) {}

    login(cred){
        var result = this.http.post(url, cred).share();
        result.subscribe(res => this.onLoginSuccess())
        return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can please share some more details? what is the difference between this and `do`?